# Cannot invoke equals(char) on the primitive type char

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and trying to nut out a basic guessing game, but I have this error. Need some help as I've set 'guess' to `char`, then want to compare it to the array of chars but tried a couple of different approaches but no joy yet.

It gives me the error on the if statement at the bottom containing:

```
(guess.equals(wordContainer[j]))
```

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String wordArray[] = {"aardvarks", "determine", "different", "greatness", "miserable", "trappings", "valuables", "xylophone"};

        double rand = Math.random() * 8;
        int x = 0;      
        x = (int)rand;      

        System.out.println(x);

        String word = wordArray[x];
        int wordCount = word.length();

        System.out.println(word);
       // System.out.println(wordCount);

        char wordContainer[] = new char[wordCount];
        char wordHiddenContainer[] = new char[wordCount];

        String input;
        char guess;

        System.out.print("Enter your guess(a-z): ");
        input = keyboard.next();
        guess = input.charAt(0);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < wordCount ; i++ ) {           
            wordContainer[i] = word.charAt(i);
            wordHiddenContainer[i] = '*';           
        }

        System.out.println(wordContainer);
        System.out.println(wordHiddenContainer);

        for (int j = 0; j <  word.length(); j++ ) {
            if(guess.equals(wordContainer[j])) {                
                wordHiddenContainer[j] = guess;

            }           
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primitives are compared with `==`. If you convert the `char`s to the wrapper classes `Character`, then you can use `.equals()`.

Either change

1. `char guess;` to `Character guess;`

   or
2. `if(guess.equals(wordContainer[j]))` to `if(guess == wordContainer[j]))`.

Comment: ...but there's no reason to. In this case, `==` is just fine and is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @kocko yeah that worked, originally i was using strings, but kept getting a mismatch char - string, which is why (i think) i was using .equals

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` is a method that is contained in the Object class and passed on through inheritance to every class that is created in java. And since it is a method, it can be invoked only by objects and not primitives.

You should compare the variable `guess` like this

```
if(guess==wordContainer[j]) {
```

hope it helps.

Comment: thought i'd added this comment yesterday, but when i came back in it wasn't there